# Using two buttons on one div, how do you fade in slowly then fade out?

Tags: html, css

The fadeout animation is not working. I think you can't put two Ids on one div.
**How do you get the fadeout to work?**
[here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sprigmendle/wqju9jh6/18/)

---

html

```
<a href="#pop">appear</a>

<div id="pop" id="pop_close">
    <a href="#pop_close">disappear</a>
</div>
```

---

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 10em;
}
#pop{
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    background: yellow;
    opacity:0;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#pop:target {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}

#pop_close:target {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadeOut 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadeOut 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadeOut 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadeOut 1s;
}



@keyframes fadeOut {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadeOut {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oogley_boogley/wqju9jh6/19/

the css:

```
#pop{
height: 10em;
width: 10em;
background: yellow;
opacity:0;
position: relative;
top: -20px;
z-index: -1;
transition: opacity 1s;  /* key style here, look into -webkit and -moz etc as well */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Exactly, **you cannot have multiple ID** on the same page,
 therefore you need to modify the ID to make `:target` a ***specific*** popup:

```
div[id^=popUp] // means: target DIV element who's ID "starts with".
```

than in the HTML you simply make the ID unique by adding a number.

```css
div[id^=popUp]{
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  background: yellow;
  opacity:0;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

div[id^=popUp]:target {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#popUp1">appear</a>
<div id="popUp1">
  <a href="#">disappear</a>
</div>

<a href="#popUp2">appear</a>
<div id="popUp2">
  <a href="#">disappear</a>
</div>
```